# Check if caller == base workspace in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Is there a pretty way to check if the *caller* workspace is actually the *base* workspace?

I guess I could easily use the `assignin` or `evalin` functions to assign something in *base* workspace and then check if that variable has changed or been assigned in *caller* workspace, but this seems to be kind of a hack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [DBSTACK](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/dbstack.html)

```
%# true if the function has been called from base
callerIsBaseWorkspace = length(dbstack) == 1;
```

Comment: is that how it is done in production code? Seems messy to use a debug function :)

Comment: @Juhl: In Matlab, you don't "compile in debug vs release mode".

Comment: Yeah I know, but the prefix `db` just doesn't seem right to me, but with what I'm doing anyway it is kind of a hack :)

Comment: @Juhl: I know what you mean. Anyway, the help specifically hints at a usage outside debugging, so you shouldn't feel too bad.

Comment: Jhul, you're right - kind of a hack.  But trying to figure out which stack frame you're in, and figure out whether or not it's the topmost frame?  Your hands are already dirty - go for it :-)  More interesting is WHY you're trying to figure this out!